# Vuetify: v-data-table in v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

I have following JSON file:

```
{ 
  "data":{ 
    "allClients":{ 
      "edges":[ 
        { 
          "node":{ 
            "allDatabases":{ 
              "edges":[ 
                { 
                  "node":{ 
                    "tnsname":"bst1rns"
                  },
                  "node":{ 
                    "tnsname":"sb_bst1rns"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add v-data-table into another v-data-table which will parse nested array inside array. Something like this:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="disClientsList.edges"
    :search="search"
    :items-per-page="100"
    :sort-by="['node.code']"
    :sort-desc="[false]"
    :single-expand="singleExpand"
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    item-key="node.code"
    show-expand
    dense>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item  }">  
    <v-data-table :items="item.node.allDatabases.edges">
      <td :colspan="headers.length">{{ node.tnsname }}</td>
    </v-data-table>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I've formatted your JSON, but it is still not completely valid. You are using two times the keyword `node` in the same object.

Comment: Actually this is what I get from GraphQL so I have different nodes in the array edges.